# Вывод списка элементов варьируемой ширины SQL-запросом

Tags: php, sql

Требуется вывести элементы в списке вот такого вида:

```
[item]

[item]

[item] [item] [item]

[item]

[item]
```

Смысл, думаю, понятен? Причём там, где идёт вывод + ещё два дополнительных `[item]`
Там должна быть связь от самого левого `[item]`. Например, по `id`
Это что-то вроде под-каталога:

- единственный экземпляр
- экземпляр, ещё один экземпляр, связанный с ним.
- единственный экземпляр

Я всё стараюсь пояснить задачу. Есть две таблицы, где хранятся одни записи основных элементов. И есть ещё одна таблица которая имеет связь с ними по `id`, где как раз и хранятся подэлементы этих элементов.

Так вы подумаете пфф задачка-то. Сделаем смешанный запрос, да и чёрт с ним.
Да, получим то, что хотели, но не то, что нужно.

В отображении. как раз таки и нужно вывести подобного рода item'ы, имея идентичную связь по всем моим описаниям.

В smarty можно было бы поставить хук на каждый элемент. который запрашивал бы по `id` каждого, нет ли у него родственника во второй таблице. Но в моём случае используется обычный шаблонизатор `index.php`, если, конечно, его так можно обозвать.

Какие могут быть варианты? Хорошо, даю чёткий пример. Картину.

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Вопрос решён. Ответили на тостере от хабры

Comment: @Арчибальдо Шпицен, вы можете ответить на свой вопрос самостоятельно. Это поможет многим людям в будущем, пришедшим в вопрос из поисковика.

Answer (score 1):

На клиенте вывод форматируй. Не умеет sql возвращать таблицы разной ширины в строках.